# Вывод на экран и в файл

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, fstream

Нужно вывести одно и то же на экран и в файл, например:

```
fout << "x = " << x;
cout << "x = " << x;
```

Как реализовать перегрузку операции <<, чтобы каждый раз приходилось писать команду вывода только один раз?

Comment: Лучше это сделать средствами ОС, а не путём перегрузки оператора вывода.

Comment: Про перегрузку оператора: http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/peregruzka-operatorov-izvlecheniya Про запись в файл: http://cppstudio.com/post/446/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы хотите внести в оператор вывода вывод `"x = "` или вывод одновременно и в файл, и на экран? И то и другое - насколько это разумно?

В первом случае, что бы вы ни выводили, все пойдет с надписью `"x ="`...

Во втором - что бы вы ни выводили в любой файл - пойдет еще и на экран...

Оно вам точно надо?..

```
class PairStream
{
public:
    PairStream(ostream& f):file(f){}

    template<typename T>
    PairStream& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        cout << t;
        file << t;
        return *this;
    }

    ostream& file;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ofstream f("log");
    PairStream p(f);
    int x = 100;
    p << "x = " << x << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы определить другой класс PairStream и перегрузить операцию вывода для этого класса, чтобы вместо двух строк написать: `PairStream s(fout); s << "x = " << x;`

Comment: @jokersobak и в чём проблема реализовать Ваше предложение?

Comment: Ну смотрите ответ, сойдет?...

Comment: В данной реализации будут проблемы с `<< std::endl` и другими манипуляторами.

Comment: @Chorkov Будут. Только я противник этого решения даже не из-за этого (и я сразу написал - что это нехорошая вещь) - а просто потому, что, например, тут резко усложняется обработка ошибок, и вообще, нарушается сам принцип, что функция должна заниматься *одним* делом, а не десятком...

Answer (score 2):

Если нет предубеждения на использование boost, можно воспользоваться этим примером 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999120/c-hello-world-boost-tee-example-program

или

```
#include <boost/iostreams/tee.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/compose.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
boost::iostreams::stream< boost::iostreams::tee_device<T1,T2> >
make_tee_ostreams(T1& arg1, T2& arg2)
{
    typedef boost::iostreams::tee_device<T1,T2> device;
    typedef boost::iostreams::stream< device > stream;
    return stream( device(arg1, arg2) );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ofstream file1("file1.txt");
    std::ofstream file2("file2.txt");
    auto file12 = make_tee_ostreams( file1, file2 );

    file12 << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение на основании [комментария ТС](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608057/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB#comment830619_608062):

> Хотелось бы определить другой класс PairStream и перегрузить операцию вывода для этого класса, чтобы вместо двух строк написать: `PairStream s(fout); s << "x = " << x;`

```
class PairStream {
public: 
    PairStream(std::ostream& one, std::ostream& two) : one(one), two(two) {}
private:
    std::ostream& one;
    std::ostream& two;
};

PairStream& operator<< (PairStream& str, const UserType& ut)
{
    str.one << ut;  // Предпологается, что для UserType реализован вывод в поток
    str.two << ut;
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void function_out (int x)
{
  m_fout << "x = " << x;
  m_cout << "x = " << x;
}
```

Comment: Это не перегрузка,  а реализованная функция.

Comment: я в курсе, просто это тоже - вполне себе решение, и даже проще, чем перегружать оператор <<

Comment: вопрос: как реализовать перегрузку